# How to configure graphite metrics reporter for kinesis data analytics application

Tags: apache-flink, metrics, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I am running a Flink application as part of the **AWS Kinesis Data Analytics service**. Flink has built in support for metrics and I have a simple counter setup that I can see is working, it is available in the flink dashboard.

Now, I want to configure graphite to be used as collecting my metrics. According to Flink this is possible: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/metric_reporters/#graphite

My problem is that I can not get the Flink application to read my configuration.
I have tried:

- Creating the file *conf/flink-conf.yaml* together with the java code but it seems to be ignored.
- Passing in a configuration override to `StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment(configuration)` , but also seems to be ignored.

How do I get metrics reported to graphite?

Comment: You can report your metrics into CloudWatch from where you can scrape them. We are doing the same, but in our case the target database is Prometheus.

Answer (score 0):

Got response from Amazon Support:
Since this is a **managed service**, it is not possible to change the configuration at this time.